# Add element works but clears input value

Tags: javascript, dom

I have a script below that adds an element to my form, another text input field. It adds the new text input field but if I type something into the first one then add a new field it removes the input text from the first one.

I cant see where im going wrong here, im fairly new to JavaScript so please go easy :)

```
function addAnother() {
  var id = 1;
  var elemebt = document.getElementById('quest');
  var number = elemebt.getElementsByTagName('*').length;
  var add = number + 1;
  var element = '<input type="text" name="question[]" id="quest'+ add +
    '" placeholder="Example: What previous experiance do you have?" class="form-control" id="cloan"><a id="name'+
    add +'" onClick="removeEle('+ add +')">Remove</a>';
  document.getElementById('quest').innerHTML += element;    
}
```

Comment: You need to use `appendChild` to append an element. Using `innerHTML` will rewrite the contents and effectively clear the values.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In JavaScript, the following two statements are practically identical:

```
str = str + ' more text ';
str += ' more text ';
```

The key point here is that in the end, the value of `str` is ***COMPLETELY OVERWRITTEN***.

In your case, that means the `innerHTML` of the "quest" element is overwritten and the browser completely recreates it's children nodes, thus reseting any state and input values.

To overcome this, you can use the `appendChild` method but you first need to create the element to append. The easiest way to do that given you have a string of your HTML is to inject that string into a dummy element using the `innerHTML` property:

```js
var target = document.getElementById('target');

var tDiv = document.createElement('div');
var htmlString = '<input type="text"></input>';
tDiv.innerHTML = htmlString;

target.appendChild(tDiv.children[0]);
```

```html
<div id="target">Keep my content safe!</div>
```

Comment: Hey, thanks for the response, this works great, but for some reason now when I add the <a> tag to the end of the htmlString its not showing, any ideas on this? Cheers for the help :)

Comment: Yes, the reason your `<a>` is missing, and so will any other element you'd add is that my code explicitly appends 1 child, the first child in the dummy div (see that `tDiv.children[0]`? that's the one...). You can either loop over all children, wrap everything in a single element (or just append the no-longer-dummy element), or use a [DocumentFragment](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/createDocumentFragment) instead of the div and append that.